# Meaning and structure of headline "Hair it is: A List of ..."

Tags: meaning, grammar

"Hair It Is: A List of Hair Words".
What are the rules for this header?
Why is the noun before it is?
Intuitively, I understand the meaning of this header. But please explain it for certainty.

Comment: Where is it from?

Comment: It's a pun. Read 'hair' instead as 'here'.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I just improved my level :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'Hair it is', as well as utilising a pun, is the construction reasonably often encountered in pronouncements such as

*Batman* it is.

Bognor Regis it is!

The theatre it is [, then].

Beans on toast it is.

This is equivalent to "So what we've decided on / to watch / to do / to have for supper ... is...

It's an idiomatic inversion of 'It is beans on toast' ('What we've decided on is beans on toast', where 'it' is semi-referential.

......

'Hair it is', punning on 'Here it is', uses 'it' even less referentially. As other answers imply, analysing beyond the echoing of 'here it is' is arguably unnecessary.

'A list of hair words' is just a fragment (here, [traditionally] a noun phrase), licensed after a colon.

Answer (score 11):

The first 'Hair' seems to be a [homophonic pun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) on the word 'here', since the article is presumably about...hair?

Comment: The words are pronounced differently; it's not a pun. Or at least, it isn't a very good one; it's a play on words. Not all plays on words are phunny. - Fun intended. (< *that* is a "homophonic pun"). Continuing the pun-line is a source of pride in my family; using *hair* for *here* would score you zero points, and it'd be time for you to rabbit. But, +1, because @Edwin... *wut?*

Comment: Don't link to mobile, please.

Comment: @Mazura that's a wikipedia problem.  Both a) they don't redirect desktop users to non-mobile, and they force mobile users to take a mobile version. (There are better ways to do that e.g. Stylesheets based on browser width that ignore mobile/desktop entirely).

Comment: @Mazura Words do not have to be pronounced _exactly_ the same to be used in a pun. "Hair" is close enough in sound to "here" for this purpose. The Wikipedia article on Pun is misleading on this point when it says "sound alike". If you look at the article on homophones, you may notice weaselly language such as "to varying extent", which leaves open the question of just how similar words have to sound in order to make a pun on them.

Answer (score 6):

In the phrase 'hair it is', 'hair' is a pun (a verbal joke) for 'here', and should be considered to function like 'here', as an adverb.

Comment: So why does this question appear on my screen as ‘unanswered’?  It has at least one perfectly good answer.